# How to specify resource library version in JSF2?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, myfaces, mojarra

Say I have a `resources/` folder in the webroot. In it, I have a `css/` folder and in it there is a `theme.css` file.

But I want to set an `Expires:` header. Therefore I want to use a version for resource libraries, say

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="theme.css"/>
```

would turn into

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="javax.faces.resources/theme.css.xhtml?ln=css"/>
```

But I want to specify something like

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="theme.css" version="1.2"/>
```

And get

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="javax.faces.resources/theme.css.xhtml?ln=css&v=1_2"/>
```

or similar. I have read that JSF2 has support for resource versioning, but **how** do I specify which version to load, and **where** do I put the files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use JSF versioning for resources in jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143383/how-to-use-jsf-versioning-for-resources-in-jar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you suppose to have the `css` library, you should use this directories naming scheme:

```
resources/css/1_1
resources/css/1_2
```

where `resources` in the jsf standard resource directory

Comment: And how do I specify the version in the JSF file? (in reality there is no version= attribute)

Comment: I found that if you don't specify version JSf takes the highest, if you want to specify a version, you can do as follow:

    `<h:outputStylesheet library="css/1_1" name="theme.css" />`

Comment: Thanks, I will try that! Though I noticed that new versions of MyFaces don't allow / characters in a library name, but I always want the latest version anyways.

Comment: Library name is also not intented to be set with resource content type, but with the common resource library name. This is indeed a pretty common mistake. I really don't understand why everyone starts using "js", "css", "image" as library name. If you don't have a library, just omit it.