# How to do versioning for JSF 2 resources?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, resources, browser-cache

When you have multiple resources (js, css, images) it's a great performance boost to set the caching policy in production environment, so that the browser won't ask each time if new version of resource is available.

The issue is, when you update the application, the browser still uses (for some time) the old resources. While with css and images it's an inconvinience, when it's JavaScript, the application will mostly not function.

The solution is well known. Either **rename** the resources (not practical) or **apppend version param** to request (such as `&ver=XYZ`).

My question is, how to do the second in **JSF 2**? So, do not change library name or create new folder for new version in resources. I want to have the request parameter appended to request, preserving resource path.

How to append such param to resources included via `h:outputScript` and `h:outputStylesheet` tags in xhtml, and via `@ResourceDependency` annotation in custom components?

At best, if it could be specified globally in application, and affecting all generated resource links.

Comment: Use the library attribute, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868068/how-to-specify-resource-library-version-in-jsf2

Comment: You mean 'version' attribute? But it is not available on @ResourceDependency.

Comment: I mean the attribute on the `h:outputScript`

Comment: But the version is not available on @ResourceDependency, so it doesn't address the issue... and the version attribute is AFAIK working so, that I must rename the folder in resources after changing it, which is practically the first solution, when I want the second. I've updated the question.

Comment: Why not use the standard resource mechanism ? When you update a library you do changes on the filesystem anyways.

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean by standard? The filesystem changes but browser makes no new request becasue the resource with that name is already in cache, so the name must change, if the browser cache is to be used.

Comment: But it's always required to rename the folder? I'd like to be able to mark the version as changed without changing the folder name. And the reason behing, PrimeFaces are making no versioning and swiching to new version would unleash chaos ...

Comment: It looks like that: javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces, no versioning (PrimeFaces 3.4)