# How to use JSF versioning for resources in jar

Tags: jsf-2, jar, resources, versioning

PF 3.5.10, Mojarra 2.1.21, omnifaces 1.5

I have a JSF library (with css files only). This library is in a .jar file. The css will be included in xhtml with 
`<h:outputStylesheet library="mylib" name="css/mycss.css">`.

In html it is rendered to  the following: `localhost:8080/cms/javax.faces.resource/css/mycss.css.jsf?ln=mylib`

CSS file of primefaces is rendered to: 
`localhost:8080/cms/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&v=3.5.10`

Notice the library version (&3.5.10) at the end. How can I do the same thing ? Should I write version in Manifest.mf. Or how can I use jsf-versioning in jar file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify resource library version in JSF2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868068/how-to-specify-resource-library-version-in-jsf2)

Comment: No, I think this not a duplicate because the question is about jar file. In jar this is different. See BalusC answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11988418/2023524)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's unfortunately not possible. Library versioning is not supported for resources in JAR.

You've basically 2 options:

1. Do it the easy and ugly way, include server's startup time as query string. Given that you're using OmniFaces, you could use its builtin `#{startup}` managed bean referring a `java.util.Date` instance in application scope:

   ```
   <h:outputStylesheet ... name="some.css?#{startup.time}" />
   <h:outputScript ... name="some.js?#{startup.time}" />
   ```

   Or perhaps you've the version already as some application variable.

   ```
   <h:outputStylesheet ... name="some.css?v=#{app.version}" />
   <h:outputScript ... name="some.js?v=#{app.version}" />
   ```

   **Update**: Notwithstanding, this doesn't work for `<h:outputStylesheet>`. See also: https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/3945 or https://github.com/javaee/javaserverfaces-spec/issues/1395

   It works for `<h:outputScript>` though, which had a very simliar bug report which was implemented pretty soon https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/1216
2. [Do the same as PrimeFaces](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/application/resource), create a custom `ResourceHandler`.

   ```
   public class MyVersionResourceHandler extends ResourceHandlerWrapper {

       private ResourceHandler wrapped;

       public MyVersionResourceHandler(ResourceHandler wrapped) {
           this.wrapped = wrapped;
       }

       @Override
       public Resource createResource(String resourceName) {
           return createResource(resourceName, null, null);
       }

       @Override
       public Resource createResource(String resourceName, String libraryName) {
           return createResource(resourceName, libraryName, null);
       }

       @Override
       public Resource createResource(String resourceName, String libraryName, String contentType) {
           final Resource resource = super.createResource(resourceName, libraryName, contentType);

           if (resource == null) {
               return null;
           }

           return new ResourceWrapper() {

               @Override
               public String getRequestPath() {
                   return super.getRequestPath() + "&v=1.0";
               }

               @Override // Necessary because this is missing in ResourceWrapper (will be fixed in JSF 2.2).
               public String getResourceName() {
                   return resource.getResourceName();
               }

               @Override // Necessary because this is missing in ResourceWrapper (will be fixed in JSF 2.2).
               public String getLibraryName() {
                   return resource.getLibraryName();
               }

               @Override // Necessary because this is missing in ResourceWrapper (will be fixed in JSF 2.2).
               public String getContentType() {
                   return resource.getContentType();
               }

               @Override
               public Resource getWrapped() {
                   return resource;
               }
           };
       }

       @Override
       public ResourceHandler getWrapped() {
           return wrapped;
       }

   }
   ```

   Or if you happen to already use OmniFaces, it could be done simpler:

   ```
   public class YourVersionResourceHandler extends DefaultResourceHandler {

       public YourVersionResourceHandler(ResourceHandler wrapped) {
           super(wrapped);
       }

       @Override
       public Resource decorateResource(Resource resource) {
           if (resource == null || !"mylib".equals(resource.getLibraryName())) {
               return resource;
           }

           return new RemappedResource(resource, resource.getRequestPath() + "&v=1.0");
       }

   }
   ```

   Either way, to get it to run, register it as `<resource-handler>` in `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` of the JAR.

   ```
   <application>
       <resource-handler>com.example.MyVersionResourceHandler</resource-handler>
   </application>
   ```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful answer. Your idea in 1 `#{startup}` is nice. So client css will be always updated and you can not forget to change the version.  Another question: Is it possible to place this ResourceHandler in jar file and use it from there ? So every jar will be independent.

Comment: Yes, put class in JAR and register it in `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` of JAR. This is also mentioned in bottom of answer, for the case you missed it.

Comment: Thank you! I am a big fan of your tutorials. They help a lot.

Comment: Excellent answer as usual. However I found that com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceImpl will use the v parameter for libraries with version info. So I made a slight change to this great example by change the parameter name. I'm using the excellent https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin to generate a git commit hash with gch as the parameter name.

Comment: I've also corrected the parameter connective using a & where libraries have been added to the path already and ? where no parameters exist on the path. https://gist.github.com/olibye/8471705

Comment: I have taken your ideas and realized it as jsf2.2 at https://github.com/SchulteMarkus/Megan/blob/master/src/main/java/com/megan/faces/application/MeganStaticFilesResourceHandlerWrapper.java - it takes the original idea from BalusC combined with maven-git-commit-id-plugin. As addition, it does not versionate primefaces-static-files or files from library "javax.faces".

Comment: Is this still true for JSF 2.2? Is library versioning now supported for resources in JAR?

Comment: @raupach: It's a technical limitation. Now you come back at it after years, if you happen to already use OmniFaces, look here how you could do it with less code: https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/resourcehandler/OmniVersionResourceHandler.java

Comment: @BalusC Was just curious. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @BalusC I like the idea with appending the startup time (or a version) to the resources. For javascript files it works, but I have the problem that css files are not found when i manually append something. Do you have an idea why this could be the case?

Comment: @marcel: bug in Mojarra.

Comment: @BalusC Thank-you! Sounds like you know it´s a bug, or do I misinterpret it?

Comment: @marcel: well, not a bug, but oversight and spec fail. See https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3941 and https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1395

Comment: @BalusC using a custom ResourceHandler, is not possible to change the version at runtime  (e.g. pulling the version code from a DB variable), without restarting server, due to resourceHandler caching.
Is there any solution to this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42886630/programmatically-clear-jsf-resource-handler-cache

Comment: ResourceHandler doesn't cache on server side at all, so I don't understand your problem in first place. You might want to reinvestigate your problem and reframe your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use your project version and append it as a version number for your resource files. This can be done using the `maven-war-plugin`. The `maven-war-plugin` will look at your pages during the build time and replace the defined properties.

The following example shows you how to configure the `maven-war-plugin` to filter your webapp resources in order to inject the custom property `asset.version`:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" ...>
  ...

  <properties>
    <asset.version>${project.version}</asset.version>    
  </properties>

  ...

  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>

          <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>gif</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>ico</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>jpg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>png</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
          </nonFilteredFileExtensions>

          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

          <webResources> 
            <webResource>
              <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory> 
              <filtering>true</filtering> 
            </webResource>
          </webResources> 

        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

The `asset.version` property can then be used in your JSF file.

Here is an example tested with JSF 2.2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ...
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">

...
<script jsf:name="js/libs/pure/pure-min.css?v=${project.version}" />
```

The result (in my case) will be the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/context-path/javax.faces.resource/js/libs/pure/pure-min.css.xhtml?v=1.0.15-SNAPSHOT"></script>
```

Comment: Good point! Thank you. It is interesting solution who uses Maven. We unfortunately don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

@Balusc response said "well, not a bug, but oversight and spec fail". It seems like css resources deployed in libraries cannot be versioned with mojarra 2.2.14. Is it right? I tried to implement your solution with a custom ResourceHandler, but resource returned by  getWrapped().createResource(resourceName, libraryName) always returns null. It seems like createResource() try to find the library's resources (like css/layout.css) with path /META-INF/resources/ but it lacks the version.

To workaround the problem i have overrided createResource method on a custom ResourceHandler which extends Omnifaces DefaultResourceHandler to add version prefix to the resourceName

```
@Override
public Resource createResource(String resourceName, String libraryName) {
    if (libraryName != null && libraryName.equals(LIBRARY_NAME)) {
        if (!resourceName.startsWith(version)) {
            resourceName = version + "/"+resourceName;
        }
    }
    return super.createResource(resourceName, libraryName);
}
```

With this workaround the generated link looks like

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/javax.faces.resource/1_0_3/css/layout.css?ln=common&amp;v=1_0_3"/>
```

for the outputStylesheet declaration

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="common" name="css/layout.css" />
```

I'm not sure this is the best workaround.