# Uses of javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE

Tags: jsf, model-view-controller, jsf-2, web, jsf-1.2

I wanted to understand impact of 'javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE' property for a JSF application. A nice use case was presented in below links

https://dzone.com/articles/jsf-20-new-feature-preview-ser 
http://www.java-tutorial.ch/java-server-faces/jsf-project-stage

Except presenting validation error messages, is there any other use case where this property really helps?  I understand that we can check this variable to identify the environment and change certain functionality, however is there anything else that JSF does automatically to help developers? Would be great if you can share the experiences from your project?

Comment: Nope. That's pretty much it: Controls how errors are logged and allows the end developer make decisions

Comment: Thanks, I got one more: JSF2.0 adds <h:messages> automatically to the view if project stage is set to Development.

Comment: I think this automatically reloads facelets. Very handy during development!

Answer (score 26):

Setting this param to `Development` enables better error messages, including in the client-side JavaScript, at the cost of some performance.

While setting this param to `Production` will turn off some error messages, and [emphasize performance](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaxj.html#giqxl).

Source:
[JSF 2.0 Reminder: Project Stage](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaxj.html#giqxl)

Answer (score 5):

According to the `comment` by wutzebaer for [this linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15066575/1017422) the `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` property may control whether or not certain features are enabled (such as resource caching).

Answer (score 3):

When we setting the PROJECT_STAGE as production we will get better error message, for example when we missed h:form tag around input fields then we may get following error message when stage is set as Development and when the stage is set as Production (or any value other than Development) we won't get any error message.

> The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion:
>   enclose the necessary components within `<h:form>`

Comment: Interesting, I though Development was always more verbose. I guess maybe while in Development, on-screen messages will be minimal, but Logging (java.util.logging) will be more extensive.

Answer (score 3):

### Cache Busting for Resources during development

By resources, I refer to static resources such as stylesheets, javascript libraries, logo's and pictograms, etc.

By default, resources are loaded without any cache expiration (expires at max age or something). This is so, because resources are assumed to be static, in that they do not change during the lifespan of the Servlet Container. We benefit that way from caching those resources on the Client Side (Web Browser caching).

However, when releasing a new version of a library that might wrap a group of resources, we do not want users to get stuck with the old version of a resource. Typically Implementations, and as per the spec, resources will get automatically suffixed with the library name and version as query attributes. A typical resource will automatically be output as something like:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/nqp-web/javax.faces.resource/components.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.2">
```

This is handled by using a specific implementation of [`Resource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/Resource.html).

So as you release new versions of a library, your users wont get stuck with old versions of resources in their cache.

However during development work, the version does not increase, but you still want the cache to expire, preferably immediately.

The default implementation is usually to make sure that based on the value of `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE`, specifically being `DEVELOPMENT`, the expire is set to immediate. You can see that in Mojarra's [`ResourceImpl`](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/application/resource/ResourceImpl.java) for example:

```java
long expiresTime;
if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isProjectStage(Development)) {
  expiresTime = new Date().getTime();
} else {
  expiresTime = new Date().getTime() + maxAge;
}
```

### Logging

As @vrcca already mentioned, a [quick search](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/search?q=isProjectStage&unscoped_q=isProjectStage) for usages of `isProjectStage` reveals that this mostly just turns on additional logging when set to `DEVELOPMENT`.

---

### References

- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11988415/744133)
- Mojarra Implementation: [`ResourceImpl`](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/application/resource/ResourceImpl.java)
- [Custom Resource Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18146091/744133)

Answer (score 1):

Another function of setting the PROJECT_STAGE as Development is that we will also be able to see our changes in .xhtml files without restarting the server.

Comment: Live changes of .xhtml files during development is handled by in-place deployment. Caching does not take place anyhow, because .xhtml is by default dynamic and will be set to expire immediately.