# Show warning when EL not found

Tags: eclipse, jsf, el, jsf-2.2

I'm creating a JSF Applikation and i would like to get some kind of warning (preferably i the console) if i make typos in my EL-Expression.

Example: 
On my page i wanted to show some Text that is localized. The locale-config in faces-config.xml is properly set up and works with the var 'msgs'.

I used this code on my page:

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg.title_edit_customer}"/>
```

When i checked my Page in the browser, nothing got showed.
I took me a while to realize that i made a typo - with `#{msgs....` it worked as expected.

Can i activate some kind of Debug-Output, so i can see directly that there is an invalid EL somewhere?

My Setup: Eclipse 4.4.2, Tomcat 8, MyFaces 2.2.8

Comment: Check if this helps... from what I remember it does...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193912/uses-of-javax-faces-project-stage

Comment: I have the PROJECT_STAGE already on Development, that dosen't help.

Comment: What EL impl do you use?

Comment: According to the https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/RELEASE-NOTES.txt  its EL 3.0 API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @SJuan76 i could figure it out:

1. Create your own `javax.el.ELResolver`, all the Methods can return null/false.
2. Open the Source of the Class `org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ScopedAttributeResolver` and copy the methods `facesContext(ELContext)` and `findScopedMap(FacesContext, Object)` (since `ScopedAttributeResolver` is final, we can't extend it).
3. Edit the getValue-Method:

   ```
   @Override
   public Object getValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
       if(!context.isPropertyResolved()){
         //Douple Check false-positives
         boolean foundInScope = false;
         final Map<String, Object> scopedMap = findScopedMap(
               facesContext(context), property);
         if (scopedMap != null) {
           Object object = scopedMap.get(property);
           if (object != null) {
               foundInScope = true;
           }
         }
         if (!foundInScope) {
           log.warn(String.format("EL-Property %s couldn't be resolved",
                   property));
       }
   }
       return null;
   }
   ```
4. Edit `faces-config.xml` to register your resolver:

   `<application>
     <el-resolver>com.myPackage.DebugELResolver</el-resolver>
   </application>`
5. Since there are many Resolvers and each one does a little bit of the Resolving, our new Resolver should come last. Add following to `web.xml`:

   `<context-param>
     <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.EL_RESOLVER_COMPARATOR</param-name>
     <param-value>org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.CustomLastELResolverComparator</param-value>
   </context-param>`
6. Now you'll get some log-Output, every time an expression couldn't be resolved:

`03.07.2015 07:34:21 com.myPackage.DebugELResolver [http-nio-8080-exec-2] WARN  EL-Property msgx couldn't be resolved`

I couldn't figure out how to get the actual EL-Expression (e.g. `#{msgx.title_edit_customer}`.