# I don't get any PropertyNotFoundExceptions although I should

Tags: jsf, el

The title almost says it all. In expression language .. expressions I can put any arbitrary property names on beans, still I just get no errors or exceptions on the server console. For example:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="stuff" value="#{bean.stuffEnabled}"
    disabled="#{bean.iGuaranteeYouThisPropertyDoesntExistadfasdfokui}" />
```

I'm just getting nothing. No Error. This really sucks for debugging. I tried googling if there is a setting to disable this somewhere but didn't find anything helpful. Actually, most results I got where concerned with the opposite, getting rid of the PropertyNotFoundException ;)

FYI: this is Mojarra v2.1.19-redhat-1 on JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA (AS 7.2.0.Final-redhat-8)

Thanks for any help or pointers in the right direction

Comment: Check your project_stage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193912/uses-of-javax-faces-project-stage

Comment: Thanks for this, too bad this also produces all kinds of other warnings and errors I don't necessarily want

Comment: Care to elaborate on them?

Comment: @Kukeltje for example all kinds of warnings for minor xhtml or jsf component nesting requirements or custom component required parameters enforcements, which are technically sensible but practically annoying as they show up in the actual rendered DOM or even prevent the application from starting because it throws hard errors and exceptions instead of just warnings. I know it's good to fix those too, obviously, but not always enough time and I would just want PropertyNotFoundExceptions, but won't get it isolated I guess, meh