# JSF refresh after "deployment"

Tags: java, jsf, caching

Is there a *simple*, *system-given* way of advicing the browser to refresh each resource once after a *fresh* deployment of a `war`-file?

I know, that a `filter` can be used to set the required headers, but still I would need to implement the logic, taking care that each resource is at least refreshed once per client.

I.e. something like appending `&deployment=2015-08-06-22-00-00` to EVERY (resource-)request performed? (this will make the browser cache the resources under the given parameter, thus refresh it after the next deployment, when the parameter has changed.)

Setting the No-Cache headers all the time is no option, because there is a huge amount of resources that would result in about 5 MB transfer amount (even gzip-encoded) per request.

I thought about using the "Expires" header for each resource, but unfortunatelly this would require to *predict* the next deployment `n`, whenever the deployment `n-1` is released...

Currently the best option is to set the expiry time to 1d, cause deployments usually happen during the late hours of a day. However, if the system is running without an update for several weeks, this will cause unnecessary data-transfers per day and client...

Comment: Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143383/how-to-use-jsf-versioning-for-resources-in-jar/

Comment: @BalusC It's not really a duplicate but the Custom ResourceHandler might be a good idea to handle this, as long as every include is a proper resource request and not vanilla-style. Thx for the link

Answer (score 0):

In case of small number of resources place them in a new folder, in our case js file changes are not getiing reflected after deployment, and now for each deployment js resources are placed in a new folder just to avoid this issue. In your case check the feasibility of keeping the resources in a new folder/location based on deploy version. will this help?

Comment: I think this might work for some projects - but for ours the number of resources is very large, so the script "relocating" the resources upon build would be a nightmare to maintain.